# ¿Cómo obtener el total de lineas de un String en Android?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un texto con saltos de linea, solo quiero contar las lineas de que se compone, su salto de linea es el especificado por el sistema.

No me refiero a `EditText.getLineCount()` ya que extraigo una parte del Texto

**Update**

Gracias al comentario de @NaCi funciona lo siguiente

```
public static int countLines(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    int total = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
        char letter = str.charAt(i);
        if (letter ==  '\n') ++count; 
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Llamenme loco pero... `letter == '\n'` No funciona? Con comilla simple...

Comment: Pues si que funciona con simple, ahora me falta saber obtener las lineas vacías sin realizar un split

Comment: Bueno mejor lo haga en otra pregunta ya que esta te la otorgo a tí.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que estas evaluando un caracter como un `String` en esta linea:

```
if (letter ==  "\n")
```

Mientras que los caracteres se asignan con comillas simples o `'`:

```
if (letter == '\n')
```

Por lo que tu código quedaría así:

```
public static int countLines(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    int total = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
        char letter = str.charAt(i);
        if (letter ==  '\n') ++count; 
    }
    return count;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Un detalle pequeño, pero los caracteres que representan los saltos de linea suelen ser diferentes por sistema operativo, según tengo entendido en windows, los saltos de linea son `\r\n` y en *NIX-like son sólo `\n`.
 *Tomado de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426404/5622844).*

Espero te haya ayudado!

Comment: Gran apunte, ya que lo necesito para sacar estadísticas de un fichero .txt que puede ser creado en cualquier sistema operativo

Comment: @Webserveis sí, el salto de línea es distinto, pero como el caracter `\n` es común es el único que necesitas contar.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes realizar el conteo de caracteres `'\n'` utilizando [`String#indexOf(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-):

```
String cadena = " ....... ";
int contador = 0;
int indice = cadena.indexOf("\n");
while (indice >= 0) {
    contador++;
    indice = cadena.indexOf("\n", indice + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera es convertir `char` hacia `String` para poder comparar con `"\n"`.

```
public static int countLines(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    int total = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
        char letter = str.charAt(i);
        if (Character.toString(letter).equals("\n")) ++count;
    }
    return count+1;
}
```