# ¿Cómo obtener el total de lineas vacias de un Texto en Android?

Tags: java, android

Obtengo texto de un `EditText` o parte de el, me gustaria obtener el total de lineas vacias, es decir

```
Lorem impsum
Lorem impsum

Lorem impsum
```

El salto de linea, contiene `\n`

¿Cómo se puede obtener el total de lineas vacías, de la forma más eficiente si es posible?

También seria interesante que si una linea vacía contenga espacio en blanco, tabulador, que a simple vista no se perciben.
Supongo que realizar un proceso linea por linea previo y realizar un `trim` se eliminara los espacios y tabuladores.

**Resultados del Benchmark**

Bucle de 10000 interaciones.

- Solución Paul vagas: 845ms
- Solución SO: 484ms
- Solución Luiggi Mendoza: 84ms

Comment: Para escoger la más adecuada, deberé de someter en Test, bucle para obtener los ms de cada método, y determinar, o si alguien con mayor conocimiento a simple vista puede detectar cual es el que consume menos memoria?

Comment: En este momento tienes alguno hecho?

Comment: Me refería de las respuestas, someterlos al mismo test de bucle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basado en [una respuesta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/14750/227) podríamos obtener el número de líneas vacías:

```
String cadena = " ....... ";
int contadorLineasVacias = 0;
int indice = cadena.indexOf("\n");
//mientras se encuentren saltos de línea
while (indice >= 0) {
    int base = indice;
    int ifinal = cadena.indexOf("\n", indice + 1);
    if (ifinal < 0) {
        break; //no se encontró nuevo salto de línea, detener
    }
    boolean vacio = true;
    for (int i = base + 1; i < ifinal; i++) {
        if (!esCaracterVacio(cadena.charAt(i))) {
            vacio = false;
            break; //detener el for
        }
    }
    if (vacio) {
        contadorLineasVacias++;
    }
    indice = ifinal;
}
```

Esto necesita de un método `esCaracterVacio(char)` que se puede implementar como sigue:

```
public static boolean esCaracterVacio(char c) {
    return c == ' ' || c == '\0' || c == '\t'; //agregar otros caracteres que consideres vacíos
}
```

Comment: Acabo de probar tu código me parece que no funciona, se queda en bucle infinito y en la linea if (!es falta un )

Comment: @Webserveis Corregido

Comment: Tu método es el más rápido, n pregunta lo de \0 que lo he visto varias veces que es?

Comment: @Webserveis es el caracter vacío, el caracter con valor 0 unicode o ASCII. Por ejemplo, si en Windows usas la combinación Alt + 64 te sale @, si utilizas Alt + 0 te sale `\0`. En lenguajes como C/C++. este caracter se utiliza como el final de una cadena de texto, pero eso no aplica a lenguajes como Java.

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que tienes un texto en una variable x partiendo de lo siguiente:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.\n
                                  \n
1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to\n 
make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also\n 
\n 
was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing\n 
               \n
like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.\n
```

Tenemos lineas con espacios en blanco *(lo que deja de ser una linea vacia)*, pienso que tu problema se podría resolver de la siguiente manera:

```
String X = " .. "; // Aquí todo el texto que pusimos arriba (ejemplo)
int i = 0; 
int LineasVacias = 0;

while (i + 1 != X.length())
{
    if (X[i] == '\n' && X[i + 1] == '\n') {
        ++LineasVacias; // Si se encuentra que el siguiente caracter está vacio, se incrementa.
        i += 2; continue; // Se salta el siguiente salto de lineay seguimos el bucle.
    }
    else if (X[i] == ' ' && X[i + 1] == ' ') {
        // Si el caracter actual + el siguiente es un espacio en blanco...
        while (X[i] == ' ') ++i; // Se incrementa i, saltando el espacio..
        if (X[i] == '\n') ++LineasVacias;
    }
    ++i;
}
```

Si es una solución algo sucia y no portable, pero me ha funcionado.
Te dejo el [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oRuo9f)  (C#) para que veas.

Comment: Le echare un vistazo

Answer (score 2):

He aquí una solución que incluye el uso de una expresión regular:

```java
String text = "Lorem impsum\n \nLorem impsum\n \nLorem impsum";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?m)^[\\t ]*$").matcher(text);
int count = 0;
while(matcher.find()) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Por [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680588/java-count-empty-lines-in-a-text-file-string) he encontrado otra manera de hacerlo

```
public static int countEmptyLines(String str) {
    final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(str));
    String line;
    int empty = 0;
    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                ++empty;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return empty;
}
```

Comment: ¿Atrapar una `IOException` al estar *leyendo* una cadena?

Comment: Android Studio me lo marcaba como "warning" y al hacer alt+intro, me recomienda try catch

Comment: @PaulVargas es una checked exception, debes manejarla.